# VBA to copy data from multiple workbooks to Mastercopy excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to extract data (Column A:I) from different workbooks in a folder (Contains same headers and layout) to a Mastercopy excel.

My code runs but it only copies data from A:E from the different workbooks. 
Each of these workbooks only have 3 rows of data (Row 1: Timestamp A:E, Row 2: Actual headers A:I, Row 3: Actual values to be extracted). I suspect its Row 1 that is causing the issue as it only has data in A:E. Any idea on how I can overcome this issue? Any advice is much appreciated.

```
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

FolderPath = "C:\Users\AlexP\Desktop\Folder\Downloads\"

Filepath = FolderPath & "*.csv"

Filename = Dir(Filepath)

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Dim erow

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & Filename)

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 9))

Filename = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you could define your objects more clearly, but to quickly address your need, I would debug by checking the value of `lastcolumn` as you execute.  You take the last column of row 1, but start copying at row 3.  Are the columns the same?  You can step through using F8 or set a breakpoint.

Comment: The files which I am copying from have 3 rows of data. Row 1 consists of timestamp and other miscellaneous items (A:E), Row 2 consists of the actual relevant headers (A:I) and Row 3 consists of the values i wish to extract. I believe its the Row 1 that is causing the problem since it only spans from (A:E). Any idea on how i can solve this? @DarrellH

Comment: Change the `1` in your `lastcolumn=` to a `3`

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly now! @DarrellH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that every workbook you're pulling data from uses columns A to I then change your copy line to `Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastrow, 9)).Copy` and that should get it to work. It won't be as resilient but it will work.

To make it resilient, make sure each worksheet has something in the first cell of each column, then you can go back to using `Columns.Count` to define the copied range.